# How to create "gcc plugins" using Eclipse?

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt

Can anyone help me. I am trying to create/build gcc plugins(c language). I dont know how to create/build "GCC PLUGINS" by using Eclipse IDE.

Note - I have already installed CDT plugin for eclipse. 
       I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 
       and have GCC-4.8.2 installed on my system.

Can anyone tell me how to create "gcc plugins" using Eclipse ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

GCC plugins are just C code, so there is nothing particularly special that you need to do in Eclipse to develop them. You will need the gcc header files (or at least some of them) to create the plugin. I have relied heavily on these:

```
#include "plugin.h"
#include "gcc-plugin.h"
#include "coretypes.h"
#include "tree.h"
#include "tree-pass.h"
#include "tree-flow.h"
```

If you are asking about an Eclipse plugin that somehow relates to gcc then I don't understand the question.

Comment: I already have plugin which can be compiled using the GCC directly. But I don't know How do I build the plugin using eclipse. Is there any procedure for this ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you compile your plugin from the command line and use it successfully? Are you asking how to compile C code in Eclipse?

Comment: I able to compile both C programs and the gcc plugins code using GCC directly from the terminal. I am also able to compile the C code using Eclipse. I am not able to understand how to compile the gcc plugins from the Eclipse IDE, and see its output in the EClipse Ide itself, So can you pls help me on this ?